# Computing the dualizing sheaf of an exceptional divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $D_1=Z(f_1)$ and $D_2=Z(f_2)$ be two plane cubics meeting in nine points $p_1,\dots,p_9\in\mathbb P^2$. The $f_i$'s induce a rational map $$(f_1,f_2):\mathbb P^2\dashrightarrow\mathbb P^1$$ defined away from $P=\{p_1,\dots,p_9\}$. Its resolution is given by the elliptic fibration
$$\pi:S=\textrm{Bl}_P\mathbb P^2\to \mathbb P^1.$$
I am trying to understand this fibration in detail. If $b:S\to \mathbb P^2$ is the blow-up map, let $E=b^{-1}(p_1)\cong\mathbb P^1$ be the fiber above $p_1$. In his [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602347v2.pdf), Ravi Vakil says (p. 20) that

> *The dualizing sheaf to the fiber at* $p_1$ *is given by* $-\mathcal O(E)|_E$.

I would like to understand why this is true. Even if it was true, I am misunderstanding something, because that would mean $\omega_E=\mathcal O_E(1)$, but isn't $\omega_{\mathbb P^1}=\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)$? Also, the claim is actually that $\omega_E$ is the conormal bundle of $E\subset S$. Do you have any intuition on why it should be so?

Thank you!

Comment: Forgive me for asking a silly question, but why doesn't Hartshorne II.8.20 give you this result?

Comment: I am the only silly one here... (Thank you)

Comment: Welcome to the club--we have jackets. :) You might want to answer your own question then, just so this isn't left unanswered!